# dnsmasq to provide public DNS service

Tags: linux, networking, dns, dnsmasq

If I'm to provide DNS service to the public using dnsmasq, how to set the `listen-address`? I changed mine from `192.168.1.1` to `0.0.0.0` and it stops working:

```
$ cat /etc/dnsmasq.d/public.conf
# listen to public
listen-address=0.0.0.0
# provide only DNS service and disable DHCP and TFTP on it
no-dhcp-interface=eth0

$ dig +short docs.google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

$ netstat -ulnp | grep :53
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                                -
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: ...why dnsmasq and not Unbound?

Comment: @grawity hmm... as long as it can get the job done. Are you willing to give detailed steps, or provide url with detailed steps? I do prefer dnsmasq though, because that's what provided by default by Ubuntu, and I assumed that there was a reason.